# Permissions in log-ins/sign-ups using PHP

Tags: php

I'm a newbie in PHP. I just want to ask how to redirect accounts that are 'admins' and 'users' to a specific page when they login.

- When I login as an admin it will be directed to a page like "superuser.php" where I can create an account for "users" in the GUI of the website.
- When the created "user" account is logged in it will be directed to a page like "user.php" with a different privilege.

The 'user' signup page is different from the 'admin' as it will be located at the admin's homepage. that is where I'm stuck at the moment

so far I did the 'admin' part.

my php code:

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    // variable declaration
    $username = "";
    $errors = array(); 
    $_SESSION['success'] = "";

    // connect to database
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','registration');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($db)) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL:" . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    // REGISTER USER
    if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
        // receive all input values from the form
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
        $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
        $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);

        // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled
        if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
        if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }

        if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
            array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
        }

        // register user if there are no errors in the form
        if (count($errors) == 0) {
            $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database
            $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) 
                      VALUES('$username', '$password')";
            mysqli_query($db, $query);

            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
            header('location: login.php');
        }

    }

    // ... 

    // LOGIN USER
    if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

        if (empty($username)) {
            array_push($errors, "Username is required");
        }
        if (empty($password)) {
            array_push($errors, "Password is required");
        }

        if (count($errors) == 0) {
            $password = md5($password);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
            $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
                header('location: home.html');
            }else {
                array_push($errors, "Wrong username or password combination");
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

my sample db:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: You should store their user level in the session and based on the type of user they are redirect them to the appropriate page. If you were using a framework all of this would have been done for you. In the users table you should have a field for user_type

Comment: @altoids the database will also be changed?

Comment: You need to be able to know what user has what permissions. How would you be able to differentiate between a user and super user? I would store it in the users table

Comment: @altoids I updated the question and posted the sample db I created

Comment: @altoids just curious how will the php script know which account is the admin and which is the user?

Comment: when you register a user you have to insert the `user_type` value in the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the users permission type `user_type` e.g. user, admin, super_user,etc

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`user_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
index(user_type)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

When they login you check their `user_type` and store it in the session
`$_SESSION['user_type'] = *their_user_type_from_the_db*`

Then redirect them to the correct page

```
$_SESSION['user_type'] = *their_user_type_from_the_db*
if($_SESSION['user_type']=='user'){
    header('location: user.php');
}elseif($_SESSION['user_type']=='super_user'){
    header('location: superuser.php');
}else{
    header('location: home.php');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. but I'm having trouble in figuring out where to insert you suggestion in my source code and will this work if the admin is the creating the accounts for the users? because in the admin page there will be another registration form to create the accounts. thank you so much!

Comment: @FrancisKane replace `header('location: home.html');` with my if statements. You're going to have to get `user_type` from `$results ` and store it in $_SESSION['user_type']

Comment: the `$_SESSION['user_type']` will be placed above the `$query`?

Comment: @FrancisKane right above `if($_SESSION['user_type']=='user'){`

Comment: the `*their_user_type_from_the_db*` I will type this as is?

Comment: there are no changes to the signup part of php script?

Comment: @FrancisKane when you insert the username and password you would have to add the user_type

Comment: so I have to create an option in the gui of the website?

Comment: @FrancisKane if thats how you're choosing to assign user_type's then yea

Comment: I hope not because there is only one admin account. and the other 'user' accounts will be created by the admin. Is there another way?

I tried it and I checked the database the first account I created is defined as the user. and it redirected me to the page assigned to the user

Comment: then dont create an option in the gui, just set the user_type to user

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled on the Database easily and allows you to control user types without the use of special code that checks for sessions beyond regular login sessions.

If you have a user table place a column in the table for `type`. 
Set a value in the table that corresponds to the type of user that they are. 
For regular users, set that value to 1, for "super users" or "admin" set it to 2. 
When they log in query the DB and check the type of user they are and if it is set to your value for regular user, only give them access to regular user data, if it is set to admin, give them access to the admin sections.

The following query would go after you have results for a user login:

```
$sql = "SELECT usertype FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
```

After you have $row information gathered into array, check for the `$row['usertype']`.

```
if($row['userType'] === 2){
    //Admin user permissions
    //Set an admin session here
    header('Location: admin.php');
    exit();
}else{
    //Regular user permissions
    //Set an reg user session here
    header('Location: loginHome.php');
    exit();
}
```